# setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) causes exception, why?

Tags: android, eclipse

why my setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) causes exception while 
        setVisibility for TextView works. I also tried set it for ImageView and it also does not work - I am getting exception too

```
public void alertdiag() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdiag_layout, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView).show();

    View Divider1 = (View) dialogView.findViewById(R.style.Divider1);
    Divider1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity"

    TextView HELP0 = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.HELP0); 
    HELP0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // this works
}
```

**alertdiag_layout.xml:**

```
<View style="@style/Divider1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HELP3"
    android:background="#000000"            
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/HELP_FIX_LINE"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HELP3"
/>  

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/HELP0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HELP_FIX_LINE"     
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="normal"
/>
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="Divider1">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You are trying to set the Visibility to a Style (R.style.Divider1). Add an Id to your View and change the R.style.Divider1 to R.id.yourNewId

Comment: I made it as an answer for you to accept

Comment: I accepted , unfortunately I have less than 15 reputations so it is not visible here..thanks a lot again :) I could not realize the mistake

Comment: juraset, I think you might be trying to upvote, which you can't do with less than 15 rep. You should still be able to accept an answer. To do that, tick the checkmark under the arrows on the answer you want to accept. (Note that you can only accept one answer.) This will let the rest of us know that this question is solved, and will give both you and that answer's author some rep.

Comment: Mike, yes you are correct I haven't noticed the checkmark until now, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the Visibility to a 
Style (R.style.Divider1)

Add an Id to your View and change the R.style.Divider1 to R.id.yourNewId

```
  <View style="@style/Divider1" android:id="@+id/yourNewId"
    android:layout_below="@id/HELP3" android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/HELP_FIX_LINE"         
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/HELP3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id attribute to your view

```
  <View style="@style/Divider1"
   android:id="@+id/my_view"
   android:layout_below="@id/HELP3"
   android:background="#000000"         
   android:layout_alignRight="@id/HELP_FIX_LINE"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@id/HELP3"
    />
```

NOTE: I switched @+id/HELP3 and @+id/HELP_FIX_LINE with @id/HELP3 and @id/HELP_FIX_LINE respectively because @+id/ is only used when you are giving a view an id. It is not used to refer other views.

Now, Change this line of code

```
 View Divider1 = (View) dialogView.findViewById(R.style.Divider1);
```

with

```
View Divider1 = (View) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

It will find the view with the given id, instead of style.

To make the view invisible you need to set

```
Divider1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

setVisibility must be used on the view, not on the style.